# WHERE column_name IN Array() returning empty array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

So i am trying to query a database table which has close to a 1000 records, and i am trying to get rows out of a table($subject) based on if a certain column(topic) value is among the values of a specific array($topics).

so my function looks like this.

```
public static function find_records($subject="", $topics=[]){

      global $database;

      foreach($topics as $key => $topic) {
          $topics[$key] = $database->escape_value($topic);
      }

      $newtopics = join("','", $topics);
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$subject." WHERE topic IN ('$newtopics')";

      $result_set = $database->query($sql);

      $object_array = array();
      while ($row = $result_set->fetch_array()) {
        $object_array[] = $row;
      }

      return !empty($object_array) ? $object_array : false;
}
```

I have a database class that handles all queries and escaping functions, it uses mysqli.
my $object_array is empty when it returns to the class that called this method. 
i tried to echo out each $row from the while loop and it worked but on exiting the while loop the $object_array is not giving anything not even'[]'. 
I think it has something to do with the 'WHERE topic IN array' part cos other queries are running ok on this method.

Comment: Not that the number of columns or 'fields' is relevant here but note that the presence of 1000 columns is sometimes symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: What is the value of `$subject` in this instance?

Comment: @RamRaider the value "sports" could be passed in as there are many subjects

Comment: @Strawberry, i meant 1000 records, the table has about 15 fields(columns).

Comment: Ah, 'rows'. Well that's different.

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop, change

```
$row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)
```

to

```
$row = $result_set->fetch_array()
```

`$database` is a [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) object instance, whereas you need [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) instance to actually fetch the results from.

Comment: changing it didnt work, i am still getting no response. but its funny cos on "echo $row;" within the while loop i am getting about 8 records being spit out.

Comment: still the same result.

Comment: Could you please show your changed code in your question? Hard to tell what's going on without seeing it. (Leave the rest of your question as is, just add the changed code in the end.)

Comment: i changed it to show you. but the result of "echo $row" now returns a MYSQLI_BOTH (showing $key-$value pairs as both numeric and attribute values)instance instead of MYSQLI_ASSOC(only attribute values) instance as it was returning before.

Comment: You can either use `fetch_assoc()` instead of `fetch_array()`, or pass the constant straight into the function - `fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside almost to show that the sql is actually correct ( this is not supposed to be a solution to the problem - though perhaps the $subject might be throwing things off? )

```
/* example data */
$subject='cars';
$topics=array('size','shape','colour','weight');

$newtopics = join("','", $topics);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$subject."` WHERE `topic` IN ( '$newtopics' );";
echo $sql;

will output
SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE `topic` IN ( 'size','shape','colour','weight' );
```